# How do I get Maven to find org.osoa.sca.annotations.Remotable from Apache Tuscany?

Tags: java, maven-2

I'm trying to put together an extremely simple proof-of-concept, but I can't get Maven to find any of the Tuscany SCA stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do you have for your dependency entry?

it should be something like this:

```
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tuscany.sca</groupId>
        <artifactId>tuscany-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Using that exact dependency definition, I still get a "1 required artifact is missing" error. I suspect that Tuscany isn't in any of the standard repos but I can't find a repo definition that has what I am expecting so I don't know if the problem is my dependency definition, a missing repo definition, or both.

Comment: Um, I looked in the central maven (2) repository to get the information.  It can be a bit confusing to do it that way, I should have just read the pom.  This works (I just tested it)

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.tuscany.sca</groupId>
  <artifactId>tuscany-core</artifactId>
  <version>1.3</version>
 </dependency>

Comment: I fixed the dependency in my answer.